# set global var using jquery and dynamic variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set a javascript global var using jquery and dynamic variable names like this:

```
var home_phone_number // located outside of any functions
.
.
.
function setPhoneVars(phone){
// do stuff here to determine the correct prefix
thePrefix = 'home_phone_'
$(thePrefix + "number").val(phone.number);

}
```

When I do this, the value of home_phone_number is undefined.

But, when I set the phone number manually, like this:

```
home_phone_number = phone.number
```

the variable is set as expected.

Comment: Why do you think it would work?

Comment: why do i think it would work? I can directly assign the value from within the javascript function WITHOUT using jquery, that's why.

Comment: jQuery is a library, a collection of functions and It simply doesn't have a function (as far as I know) to set the value of a variable. `$(thePrefix + "number")` Will look for an HTML element like `<home_phone_number>`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Global variables are properties of the `window` object, so can be accessed as such:

```
window[thePrefix+'number'] = phone.number;
```

Comment: that worked. Thanks. But still I wonder why the jQuery code did not, and is there a syntax change I could have made to make it work?

Comment: Because the jQuery code makes bugger all sense, that's why it didn't work.

Comment: bugger all sense. I like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can access global variables through `window` object, e.g.

```
var home_phone_number = "value";

function setPhoneVars(phone) {
    var thePrefix = "home_phone_";
    window[thePrefix + "number"] = phone.number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having such many globals.. you can use a single object..

```
var globals = {
   home_phone_number: 0 // located outside of any functions
} 


function setPhoneVars(phone){
  // do stuff here to determine the correct prefix
  thePrefix = 'home_phone_'
  globals[thePrefix + "number"] = phone.number;
}
```

Comment: Technically, by using global variables, you already are using a single object: `window`.

Comment: @Kolink True, I understand the above is additional wrapper.. but this I believe is is more like inside a group.. Something like `window.pluginA.property` and `window.pluginB.property`

Answer (score 0):

I think your use of JQuery is not appropriate; .val() is intended to set the value of HTML elements, i.e. HTML objects in the DOM.

To simply set a dynamic JavaScript variable you could use eval() which is a JavaScript function which treats a string as executable code;

```
thePrefix = "home_phone_";
eval(thePrefix + "number = phone.number;");
```