# get the value of a var in the script

Tags: javascript, html

```
var first = "a whole lotta stuff";
var second = "first";
document.querySelector("input").value = second;
```

right now the value of the input will be "first". I want it to be "a whole lotta stuff".
in other words, I want the value of the input to be the var first and not just a string of "first".

Comment: So that if `first` changes, `document.querySelector("input").value` should also change?

Comment: "_right now the value of the input will be "first"_" [No it isn't](https://jsfiddle.net/3yx1ujkb/)?

Comment: basically. I made it a simple as possible.

Comment: As written, this code already works the way you want it to. What does your actual code look like? I'm assuming it's something different and you accidentally fixed the problem in translation.

Comment: when I ran it in Visual Studio it was. what should the value be?

Comment: Run it in a browser.

Comment: var nameNum = "name" + productNum;
    document.querySelector("[name=name]").value = nameNum;

//there are vars name1,  name2, etc..//when I ran it I got value="name2"

Comment: right. I messed up the code. editing...

Comment: You can't do that in JavaScript. You can do some things *like* that, but HTML elements don't "see" the JavaScript realm in a way that would do what you want.

Comment: **I want the value of the input to be the var first and not just a string of "first".** What you are saying is extremely confusing. If you want it to be the variable `first` do `document.querySelector("input").value = first;`, is there a problem with that?

Comment: Not sure why you'd expect the field to contain the value in `first` if you're never referencing it

Comment: Based on the code in that comment (again, please put your *actual code* in the question, because your dummy code is still missing relevant details), it looks like your real problem is with accessing a dynamic global variable, in which case see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018552/set-global-var-using-jquery-and-dynamic-variable-name

Comment: Alternately, consider using an array instead of numbered variables.

Comment: that is what I am trying to achieve. I can't set the value as first, as it is a string that was received from the program. (see the original code commented earlier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the additional information you provided in your comment:

```
var nameNum = "name" + productNum;
document.querySelector("[name=name]").value = nameNum;
//there are vars name1, name2, etc..
//when I ran it I got value="name2"
```

You need change the way you try and access the variables `name1`, `name2`, etc.

The solution is to nest `name1` and `name2` inside an object and access the keys by building the string within [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors). Like this: `names['name' + productNum];`

Check out this example:

```js
var names = {
  name1: 'foo',
  name2: 'bar',
}

var productNum = 2

document.querySelector('input').value = names['name' + productNum];
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed double quotes around first in second line.

```
var first = "a whole lotta stuff";
var second = first;
document.querySelector("input").value = second;
```

Including double quotes makes "first" a string that is assigned to second. Without quotes first is a reference and the value of first is assigned (copied) to second.